# Updated facebook FB.init error in login

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using JavaScript SDK of Facebook for signup with Facebook button in my site. I have used this script:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <img onclick="fb_login();" src="public/images/facebook_signup.jpg" id="fb-login" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-top: -1px; cursor: pointer;" alt="Sign up with facebook">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({appId: '423901a20718dce67e82992eeb6f41bf', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});
        function fb_login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                }
            },{scope:'email,user_birthday,offline_access,publish_stream,read_friendlists'});
        }
        function fb_logout() {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                }
            });
        }
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                // A user has logged in, and a new cookie has been saved
            } else {
                // The user has logged out, and the cookie has been cleared
            }
        });
    </script>
```

But when click on button then it gives an Facebook error "An error occurred. Please try again later.".

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- That ID '423901a20718dce67e82992eeb6f41bf' you have in your FB.init() is not a facebook APP ID.
- Also you're missing your channelURL from your FB.init parameters.
- You should be checking getLoginStatus() per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/